# Brightcove smart api functions dont work on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, brightcove

I ' am using brightcove smart api (not flash only) and with chrome and firefox everything goes great.
But in IE(i m using 11 but i believe this problem will be also in older "IE" browsers) some of the Function callbacks return undefined like "getCurrentVideo"

```js
APIModules = brightcove.api.modules.APIModules;
experience = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID) 
myVideoPlayer = experience.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER); 
myVideoPlayer.getCurrentVideo(function (currentVideo){
    // currentVideo== undifind
})
```

Is there a known problem with smart api and internet explorer?

Comment: Do you have a demo or some code that we can look at?

Comment: APIModules = brightcove.api.modules.APIModules;
experience = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID)
myVideoPlayer = experience.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
myVideoPlayer.getCurrentVideo(function (currentVideo){
// currentVideo== undifind
})

Comment: looks like your code is missing a semicolon or is that just a typo? experience = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID) myVideoPlayer = experience.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);

Comment: no no,
the code is fine, its works on crome and firfox.
do you able to invoke "getCurrentVideo" in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass proper param to Brightcove `<object>` tag

```
<object id="myExperience928199562001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
    <!-- other params here -->
    <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
    <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="myTemplateLoaded" />
    <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady" />
</object>
```

and setup experiences and modules in `templateLoadHandler` and `onTemplateReady` events.

I've copied their page from http://files.brightcove.com/content.html, and added a log button in JsBin http://jsbin.com/bihecaloki. IE seems to be working fine.

Hope this helps.